# Xcode 9 Visual Memory Debugger broken

Tags: debugging, xcode9

With the Xcode 9 GM, I can't seem to get the visual memory debugger to work. Clicking on the memory graph icon just pauses the program, but nothing else happens. Scheme: NSZombie detection is disabled, memory logging is enabled.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rebooting the computer fixed it. Leaving the Q&A here for everyone with the same problem.

Comment: Yes, that‘s not quite macOS-like... but rather like the „other“ operating system.

Comment: Reboot doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my iPad worked for me.